Can't import typescript type?
I can't find how to import the type ExportProgress from dexie-export-import:
If I do:
  import "dexie-export-import";

  function progressCallback ({totalRows, completedRows, ...restProps} : ExportProgress) {
    console.log(`Progress: ${completedRows} of ${totalRows} rows completed`);
    return true;
  }

then I get an error:
Error: Cannot find name 'ExportProgress'. 

If I do:
  import type { ExportProgress } from "dexie-export-import";

then I get an error Error: Module '"dexie-export-import"' has no exported member 'ExportProgress'. Did you mean to use 'import ExportProgress from "dexie-export-import"' instead? (ts).
The library exports it here via:
export interface ExportProgress {
  totalTables: number;
  completedTables: number;
  totalRows: number | undefined;
  completedRows: number;
  done: boolean;
}

Any idea what I'm missing? I'm using sveltekit + vite, and I tried to change in tsconfig.json the {"compilerOptions": {"moduleResolution": "bundler"}} into:
{"compilerOptions": {"moduleResolution": "node", …}}

without success

Seems like it's an issue on their side. The interface you're trying to use is exported from that file but not from the library it seems. The index.ts file in their src folder just re-exports everything from dexie-export-import.ts and I don't see that interface exported there. Seems like they probably forgot to make it public. They need to explicitly re-export that interface from either index.ts or dexie-export-import.ts.
I see you already filed an issue in their git repo, just ask them to re-export it, or you can do it yourself and submit a pull request :)

Great, you were right, I created a PR here https://github.com/dexie/Dexie.js/pull/1971 (and I need to use then import type { ExportProgress } from "dexie-export-import";)

Thanks for the PR. A new version of the addon will be out later today!

Your answer is in the error message:
Did you mean to use 'import ExportProgress from "dexie-export-import"' instead? (ts)

Try
import ExportProgress from "dexie-export-import";


Thanks, but no, this will just try to name the default export into ExportProgress, it will not pick the ExportProgress interface. Doing so results in the error Error: 'ExportProgress' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof ExportProgress'? (ts). (And no, typeof is not the solution either)
